# WTForms Validators not Working except DataRequired()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm building a website using Python, Flask, and WTForms. I built a form webpage and tried to add Validators to the form. However, I found that only DataRequired() is working. The other validators aren't reporting any error even when I deliberately input wrong values.

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm,Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, IPAddress

class FooForm(Form): # I tried both FlaskForm and Form
    ip = StringField('IP Address', validators=[DataRequired(),IPAddress()])

    button = SubmitField('Submit')
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def foo():
    foo_form = FooForm()

    return render_template('foo.html', form=foo_form)
```

/templates/foo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Foo</h2>
<form method="post">
    {{ form.ip.label() }}
    {{ form.ip() }}

    {{ form.button.label() }}
    {{ form.button() }}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example GIF:
[image]

As you can see, DataRequired() is working, but not so for IPAddress(), plus basically any other validators I've tried.

{% form.ip.error %} also is empty.

Anyone know why this is happening? Or should I just build a form with scratch HTML?

***Python 3.10.8; Flask 2.2.2; Flask-WTF 1.0.1; WTForms 3.0.1***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are working, but you are not validating the form with `foo_form.validate_on_submit()`.

Some validations are setting the attributes for the `<input>` tags. Therefore they can be instantly validated on the html side. Others are not setting them and only validate the input on the backend. Look for the following statement under `wtforms` documentation:

> Sets the *required* attribute on widgets.

`Length` is something that can be set via an attribute, however `IPAddress` requires you to use `validate_on_submit()`.

```py
class FooForm(FlaskForm):
    ip = StringField("IP Address", validators=[DataRequired(), IPAddress()])
    button = SubmitField("Submit")


@app.route("/foo", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def foo():
    foo_form = FooForm()
    if foo_form.validate_on_submit():
        return "validated"

    print(foo_form.errors)
    return render_template("foo.html", form=foo_form)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Foo</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}  <!-- Make sure to include this line for CSRF protection -->
    {{ form.ip.label() }}
    {{ form.ip() }}

    {{ form.button.label() }}
    {{ form.button() }}
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```
# Output
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2022 11:37:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'ip': ['Invalid IP address.']}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working now! But is it possible to make it dynamic? i.e. prompts the error message as the input box loses focus?

Comment: You have to look into `flask.flash` for that functionality. Can you also mark the answer as accepted please ?